# How to properly use the "second" ordinal number with the "second" time unit?

Tags: measuring-units, ordinal-numbers

What I'm trying to say:

"Look carefully at the second second of the video."

This might be grammatically correct but it's weird to use. What are some better ways to say it?

Context:

- The sentence is a comment on a website.
- The video is around ten seconds.
- The time should be precise.
- The video doesn't have a time info as it plays if the viewer is not a power user.

Comment: I don't know of a better way to *say* it. Writing it, you could use *2nd second* instead.

Comment: You could say "Look at second number two of the video."

Comment: I think I'd probably say "Look at the start of the video". Can a viewer be so precise as to observe a discrete second, such as the second second?

Comment: If the video is less than an hour, times are displayed as 00:00.  I'd say "The film clip is at 00:01-00:02, just a second long and beginning one second into the video.  You can leave off the leading 0.

Comment: This sort of thing happens a lot in English.  If you think that that is a problem, take it up with Noah Webster & WhateverHisName Oxford.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In writing, you can take advantage of the differences in writing the two:

> Look at the 2nd second of the video.
>
> Look at the second sec. of the video.
>
> Look at second #2 of the video.

If, in context, you have reason to refer to "the first second" (which only seems weird if you stare at it, and pretty much anything does that), you can follow with

> Then, look at the next second of the video.

But in general I think "the second second" is fine. *Especially* in speaking rather than writing:

> Look at the **sec**ond second of the video

has a stress and tonal pattern on the first syllable of the first "second" that makes it quite clear.

It may look weird but sometimes the weird way is still the best way to write something — like some cases of "had had" or "that that".